# Recurrent Neural Networks for Drawing Classification tutorial code doesn't run on tensorflow 2

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, c#-2.0

I'm a beginner in deep leaerning and Tensorflow.

I tried to run the tutorial code for [Recurrent Neural Networks for Drawing Classification](https://github.com/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/r1/tutorials/sequences/recurrent_quickdraw.md) on my computer following the directions written there. But the provided tutorial code file didn't run on Tensorflow 2.8.0, apparently due to Tensorflow version difference.
I upgraded the code using tf_upgrade_v2 to make it compatible with Tensorflow 2.
But the updated code still had 'tf.contrib' codes, which are not compatible with Tensorflow 2 and have to be mannualy updated.
I have no idea how to do it.

I would appreciate if I could get some advice here on how to update 'tf.contrib' parts of the tutorial code manually to run it on Tensorflow 2.

Here's the details of what I did.
(System: Windows 10 Pro 64-bit, python 3.8.12, Jupyter Lab 3.2.1)

1. I installed Tensorflow 2.8.0 in Anaconda.
2. I downloaded the tutorial code [train_model.py](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tensorflow/models/r1.13.0/tutorials/rnn/quickdraw/train_model.py) from [Recurrent Neural Networks for Drawing Classification](https://github.com/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/r1/tutorials/sequences/recurrent_quickdraw.md)
3. I downloaded the data file from [here](http://download.tensorflow.org/data/quickdraw_tutorial_dataset_v1.tar.gz) and unzipped it.
4. In Jupyter Lab, I ran the following code

```
      %run -i train_model.py --model_dir=model_dir\
    --training_data=rnn_tutorial_data/training.tfrecord-?????-of-????? \
    --eval_data=rnn_tutorial_data/eval.tfrecord-?????-of-????? \
    --classes_file=rnn_tutorial_data/training.tfrecord.classes
```

I added `--model_dir=model_dir`because the first run produced an error saying "*ValueError: model_dir should be non-empty*."

I ran the code above and got an error saying "*AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'app'*".

5. I learned through search that 'app' is no longer used in Tensorflow 2. So I upgraded the train_model.py using **tf_upgrade_v2** program as shown in [the Tensorflow Core](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate/upgrade) page.

The  output report of tf_upgrade_v2 gave numerous warnings and errors like following:

```
175:13: WARNING: Using member tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMBlockCell in deprecated module tf.contrib.rnn. (Manual edit required) tf.contrib.rnn.* has been deprecated, and widely used cells/functions will be moved to tensorflow/addons repository. Please check it there and file Github issues if necessary.
175:13: ERROR: Using member tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMBlockCell in deprecated module tf.contrib. tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMBlockCell cannot be converted automatically. tf.contrib will not be distributed with TensorFlow 2.0, please consider an alternative in non-contrib TensorFlow, a community-maintained repository such as tensorflow/addons, or fork the required code.
```

6. But anyway, I ran the updated code in Jupyter Lab. Not surprisingly, I got the error, "*AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'contrib'*".
7. I searched for information on tensorflow/addons, but couldn't find one that tells me how they can substitute the 'contrib' codes.

Comment: Should I just go back to Tensorflow 1.15?

Comment: I downgraded Tensorflow to 1.15.0 and could avoid tf.contrib errors/warnings. Instead, I encountered new errors, but that's another issue.

Comment: [Here's the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71317522/cant-fix-module-tensorflow-has-no-attribute-estimator-on-tensorflow-1-15) I posted when I tried the same with Tensorflow 1.15. To this date, I haven't had success yet in running this drawing classification program either with 2.0 or 1.15 of Tensorflow.